# Which is better in a makefile: top down or bottom up target grouping?

Tags: makefile

I'm writing a makefile from scratch for the first time and am playing around with creating some `.PHONY` targets which build a convenient subset of my project.

For example, let's say I have 6 source files:

```
file1a.tex
file2a.tex
file3a.tex
file1b.tex
file2b.tex
file3b.tex
```

Each can be compiled (by LuaLaTeX) into a pdf file and I have a rule which tells make how to do that:

```
%.pdf : %.tex
        lualatex %<
```

Now, I'd like to create 3 `.PHONY` targets for convenience sake.  One will compile all the `*a.tex` files, the second the `*b.tex` files, the third is `all`.  Further, as I will continue to add files to this project, I'd like the file sets to be built automatically as much as possible.  Now, as I see it, I have two possible strategies before me:

Strategy 1 (create master set with wildcard and then use filter to create the subsets):

```
sources := $(wildcard *.tex)
a_sources := $(filter %a.tex,$(sources))
b_sources := $(filter %b.tex,$(sources))
```

Strategy 2 (create subsets with wildcard and then amalgamate into master set):

```
a_sources := $(wildcard *a.tex)
b_sources := $(wildcard *b.tex)
sources := $(a_sources) $(b_sources)
```

Once each of those sets is established, the targets can be create with substitution references:

```
.PHONY : target_a target_b all

target_a : $(a_sources:.tex=.pdf)
target_b : $(b_sources:.tex=.pdf)
all : target_a target_b
```

My question is which of these strategies will be more productive long-term?  That is, as I add more and more files (and possibly want to create other desirable subset targets) which of these strategies will lead to faster performance by make?  And what about potential problems?  Do either of these methods have potential pitfalls that I'm not seeing?

Comment: I don't think it matters much. Either will work, and the choice will have a negligible effect on performance -- since the time to construct the lists is negligible when added to the compilation time -- so it comes down to which method you find more intuitive and easier to read. (I am making this a Comment, because the way this month is going, if I commit to it as an Answer, chances are MadScientist will Answer thirty seconds later and show that making the wrong choice will raze your city).

Comment: :)  I agree there's no difference here.  I can't see any way in which you'd get different results, and I would be astonished if you could detect any performance difference between them.  A cynic might say that the system globbing code used by `wildcard` would be better performing than make's `filter` so strategy 2 might be faster but I can't imagine the number of files you'd have to get up to before you could perceive it.

Comment: I would use the `$(wildcard)` method, since in the end you don't seem to use `$(sources)` anyway. Note also that those are not equivalent, since with the `$(filter)` approach `$(sources)` may actually contain more files than just `$(a_sources)` and `$(b_sources)`; it would probably be just a waste of computing, especially when you don't use `$(sources)` itself.

Comment: Actually, `$(sources)` itself is used elsewhere in the makefile (as part of automatic dependency determinations).  Since I did that first (or rather second, with the original individual file build rules being first), I already have `$(sources)` defined using `$(wildcard)` and it was only as I started creating the subsets using the same method that I realized I was having make do duplicate work and came up with these two possibilities to avoid that.

Comment: Further, in my project the two methods are currently equivalent because all tex files are either a type or b type.  I expect that will remain, even if I introduce new types as then I'd probably introduce a new convenient target for the new type.

Comment: Given the consensus here in the comments, @Beta would you like to turn your comment into an answer for me to accept?

Comment: Thank you, but I don't think I've earned it. You can post an Answer yourself, though, with a summary of the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The consensus is that the choice doesn’t matter so long as the sunsets are both complete and exclusive (i.e. each file is in one and only one subset).  Strategy 2 (using multiple wildcard expressions) is probably faster, but the savings are so marginal that one would have to have a whole lot of files before the savings became noticeable (and even then, would be dwarfed by the actual build time).  As such, the decision between the two strategies is best made based on the readability and maintainability of the makefile.  Since I think better in terms of building up from smaller pieces, I’m going with Strategy 2.